# Pandas filter rows using multiple fields together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like this:

```
In [34]: people = pandas.DataFrame({'name' : ['John', 'John', 'Mike', 'Sarah', 'Julie'], 'age' : [28, 18, 18, 2, 69]})
         people  = people[['name', 'age']]
         people

Out[34]:    
    name    age
0   John    28
1   John    18
2   Mike    18
3   Sarah   2
4   Julie   69
```

I want to filter this `DataFrame` using the following tuples:

```
In [35]: filter = [('John', 28), ('Mike', 18)]
```

The output should look like this:

```
Out[35]: 
    name    age
0   John    28
2   Mike    18
```

I've tried doing this:

```
In [34]: mask = k.isin({'name': ['John', 'Mike'], 'age': [28, 18]}).all(axis=1)
         k = k[mask]
         k
```

However it shows me both Johns because it filters each column independently (the ages of both Johns are present in the `age` array).

```
Out[34]: 
    name    age
0   John    28
1   John    18
2   Mike    18
```

How do I filter rows based on multiple fields taken together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
people.set_index(people.columns.tolist(), drop=False).loc[filter].reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### Cleaned up and with explanation

```
# set_index with the columns you want to reference in tuples
cols = ['name', 'age']
people = people.set_index(cols, drop=False)
#                                   ^
#                                   |
#   ensure the cols stay in dataframe

#   does what you
#   want but now has
#   index that was
#   not there
# /--------------\
people.loc[filter].reset_index(drop=True)
#                 \---------------------/
#                  Gets rid of that index
```

Comment: I gave a very simplistic example; I actually have a dataframe containing 5 million rows and 28 columns. This solution is fast and elegant :)